# bash script unexpected else in for loop

Tags: bash

this script tries to ping through a hosts string array.

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "check if $i is online"
   ping -c1 $i &>/dev/null
   if[ $? -eq 0 ] then
        echo "$i is online"
   else
        echo "$i is not online"
   fi
done
```

I am new to bash scripting so if some one could tell me why I get an

syntax error near unexpected token `else'

and also if this is a good approach. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please paste your code in http://www.shellcheck.net/ You have a typo in `if[ $?`, which should have a space after `if`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[` is not part of `bash`'s syntax; it is a regular character like `a` or `8`. As such, the parser does not recognize `if[` as two words `if` and `[`; it just sees the name `if[`, which it assumes might be a command name followed by a series of arguments terminated by the end of the line. The following line is also a valid command. The *next* line, though, begins with `else`, which is a recognized keyword and thus cannot occur in command position, but only as part of an on-going `if` statement, triggering the error.

All of which is to say, you *must* separate `if` and `[` with a space.

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
```

(You also need a semi-colon before `then` if it appears on the same line, which would be the next problem you encountered after fixing the space issue.)

Answer (score 4):

The line number 6, should have been with a semi-colon `;` and need a space after the `if` in `if[ $?` of your line.

```
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
```

More recommended way is you can directly use `ping's` exit-code in if-statement as

```
if ping -c 1 "$i" &> /dev/null
then
    echo "$i is online"
else
    echo "$i is not online"
fi
```

See the below excerpt from the `man ping` page on why I used the `-c` flag.

```
-c count
         Stop after sending count ECHO_REQUEST packets. With deadline option, ping waits for count ECHO_REPLY packets, until the timeout expires.
```

Use http://www.shellcheck.net/ , to debug such trivial syntax errors.

Comment: You also fixed the lack of space between if and [

Comment: `;` is a semi-colon, and that is a problem, but not the immediate problem.

Comment: @Lennart: Thanks for the comment, refer my update now!

Comment: @chepner: I fixed it in the example I gave, but didn't mention it then, did now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then` You need to have a space between the `if` and the `[` and also you missed a `;`